# Query same table with pivot table

Tags: mysql, laravel, pivot

I have following tables:

**users** - id, username, etc.
**conversations** - id, private, etc.
**conversation_user** - id, user_id, conversation_id

There are two records in the **conversation_user** table for each open/started conversation (could be more if a conversation is multi user).
One for user as recipient/recipients, another for a user as sender. Let's say: **user_id=1**, **conversation_id=1** and **user_id=2**, **conversation_id=1**.

How can I select all users/usernames I have an open conversation with. All the participants, to be exact.

I assume I need to get a conversation id's I'm a participant at and then do a reverse lookup for other users in the conversation. But no luck so far... This reverse lookup is where I got stuck.
I'm playing with Laravel 5.3 and MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need a `has_started_conversation` kind of boolean on your pivot table, `conversation_user`.

As noted in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many), you need to define the relationships between your `Conversation` and `User` models.

User

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function conversations()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Conversation')->withPivot('has_started_conversation');
    }
}
```

Conversation

```
class Conversation extends Model
    {
        public function users()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withPivot('has_started_conversation');
        }
    }
```

Then

```
//  get a users conversations
$conversations = \App\User::first()->conversations;
// select a single conversation, or maybe multiple with a for loop?
$important_conversation = $conversations->random();
// get the participants of that conversation
$participants = $important_conversation->users;
```

Comment: Do I really need that boolean? When I start a conversation it automatically creates records in conversations and conversation_user tables. Conversations ID is a connection between all participants and a proof the conversation has started, IMHO...

Comment: you can rely on the first user that is attached on the conversation, but then you'll need to track timestamps. Its your choice.